# How can I grab the character value of a string, given an index ... in some Sql code?

Tags: sql, t-sql, indexing

i've got some string in some sql. i need to find out what the character is, for that string, given a index.

eg.

```
DECLARE @someString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'hi folks'
DECLARE @index INT = 4 -- assuming the first index is 1, not 0.
```

now .. how do i get the character at 4th index slot, which is an 'f', in that example above.

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
DECLARE @someString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'hi folks' 
DECLARE @index INT = 4 -- assuming the first index is 1, not 0.
SELECT SUBSTRING(@someString, @index, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function.

```
SUBSTRING ( value_expression ,start_expression , length_expression )

SELECT SUBSTRING ( @someString, @index, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@someString, @index, 1)
```